# Django Admin Fieldsets

Tags: django-admin, django-forms

Trying to understand Django Admin a bit better, but I find the Django documentation a bit lacking sometimes (or perhaps my capacity to understand).

I know you can use fieldsets to control the layout of certain admin pages. What I can't seem to grasp is what the fieldset names are.

If I have the following class

```py
class Demo(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

and Admin class as the following

```py
class DemoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'City')
```

In this, albeit contrived example, what possible fieldsets could I use?

Comment: You'd probably want a more complex model before you went down the road of fieldsets. Personally, I think the documentation of fieldsets is pretty good: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

Comment: I'll agree it would be more appropriate with a more complex model. This isnt my actual model. As for the documentation.. i have been unable to find anything that actually tells you what the fieldset names are.. i.e do all variable names become fieldset names.. what are the "buitl-in" fieldsets called?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what fieldsets are. It's just a way for you to be able to group the fields on a Model Admin Page. Just implement the example in the documentation and it should become apparent for you.

Answer (score 66):

Try this, and you'll soon see how it looks/works.

```py
class DemoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('name', 'city')
  fieldsets = (
      ('Standard info', {
          'fields': ('name')
      }),
      ('Address info', {
          'fields': ('address', ('city', 'zip'))
      }),
   )
```

When you go to the change-page to edit, you'll get one box "standard info" with the name-box. And you'll get another box that says "address info" with the adress field first, and then the city and zip-fields on the same line after.

Comment: @Consiglieri If it worked it's normal to click the "accepted answer" button :)

Comment: But it's not showing up in the ADD PAGE, But the document says so, Is there something else I have to do to get the model name.